# How to create package for .deb file

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package

Hi I have created .rpm packages successfully for fedora FC10 linux. I can cretae .rpm file of my application similarly I want to create .deb file of my application. I want step-by-step approach to create debian packager. Please help me to create .deb file for my application

I am using ubuntu linux to create packager

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Ubuntu, go to the MOTU wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU It has all what you need instructions step-by-step, a irc channel and even scheduled remote courses. Also check: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Packaging

A good summary: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/x169.html

Answer (score 1):

See `man dpkg-deb` (`--build` command) and `man deb-control`.

`.deb` file creation with `DEBIAN` directory instead of `debian` one is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/336